# Issue with jQuery ui dialog widget (change url of page)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a link that its href is set.I 've assigned jQuery ui dialog to it,so after clicking this link a confirmation dialog box opens.I the page url change to link href attribute if the user click on 'Ok' button of confirmation dialog box.

How can i change location of window with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to do that, you can use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location):

```
window.location.replace($("#yourLinkId").attr("href"));
```